# UTF8String Properties in C++Builder 2010

Tags: unicode, utf-8, properties, c++builder, vcl

I have a component with a UTF8String property like this.

```
class TForm6 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
private:    // User declarations
UTF8String u;
public:     // User declarations
  __fastcall TForm6(TComponent* Owner);
  __published:
  __property UTF8String UTF8 = {read = u, write=u};
};
```

When I attempt to read the RTTI of the property it comes back as AnsiString, with Codepage of zero rather than 65001.

```
__fastcall TForm6::TForm6(TComponent* Owner)
  : TForm(Owner)
{
  PPropInfo pp =GetPropInfo(this, "UTF8");
  PTypeInfo pt = *(pp->PropType);   // pt->Name = "AnsiString"
}
```

The problem this gives is that attempts to load a Unicode string from a DFM file result in slews of "???" due to forcing the string to be Ansi.

Using Delphi with a UTF8String property works as expected. The RTTI `Typeinfo^.Name` is "UTF8String".

I think this is a C++Builder 2010 bug?

Is there any easy workaround/hack (apart from defining properties as UnicodeString), and does anyone know if the bug is fixed in newer versions?

Comment: Unlike in Delphi, `UTF8String` is not its own type in C++, it is just an alias for `AnsiStringT<65001>` (even `AnsiString` is an alias for `AnsiStringT<0>`). In any case, AnsiString RTTI doesn't work very well in C++, and never has. You are better off getting such RTTI from Delphi instead. The DFM streaming system is written in Delphi, so it is going to use Delphi RTTI anyway.

Comment: Besides, a DFM can stream `UnicodeString` using UTF-8 internally, but that doesn't change the fact that the system still expects `UnicodeString` for input and output. You should be using `UnicodeString` (or `System::String`) for your property type (you can use `UTF8String` for your internal storage, just use getter/setter methods for the property). The code you showed works fine for `UnicodeString`, as it is a distinct type in both Delphi and C++.

Comment: Thanks Remy. So the latest XE with clang compiler is no different? :( Exposing UnicodeString properties with UTF8 storage was my fallback. I was contemplating a hack to `SetRawByteStrProp` in typinfo.pas, but the only one I can see is to assume that converting Unicode to any AnsiString type *always* converts to UTF8 and that 's likely to cause more issues than it fixes!

Comment: I don't know if the problem still exists in the latest version, I didn't try it yet. But I did reproduce it in XE2